# Unable to increase image title field length in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-fields

I want the caption/title to be set > 300. However, I notice that even though the field is set to accept a maximum of 500. In the database the 'field_image_title' column is set to 128. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to the post above.  I used the file_entity module to create fields for files and my problem was solved. see http://drupal.org/project/file_entity

Luckily, file_entity was available for drupal 7 already.

For those who encountered the same problem, file_entity is a good way to go :)